# Percentage with Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation

Based on the picture below, there is a value with a percentage that is 68 and 95 percent in relation to standard deviations in a normal distribution.

My question is:
What do the 68 and 95 percentages represent?

Please remember that I'm a newbie in statistics.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The percentages can be interpreted this way:

For a random sample drawn from a Gaussian distribution with parameters $\mu$ (i.e. the population mean) and $\sigma^2$ (i.e. the population variance), you can expect about 68% of the observations to lie in the interval $\mu \pm \sigma$, and about 96% of the observations to lie within $\mu \pm 2\sigma$.

Comment: Took the liberty of editing, given the OP's ID as a newbie in stats.

Comment: observations? The people from the sample are observation?

Comment: @FullMetalGame the people are not the observations, but their measured values (for example, their heights), are the observations. The people are the "statistical units" or "sampling units" or, more generally, the "*units of analysis*." Not to be confused with "*units of measurement*," which is the scale by which we measure their heights. One might say something like, "we *observe* the height of each *unit*."